# use height of another element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use the height of an object for another one. If the height of object 1 changes (read more button), the height of object 2 should change as well. Do I have to use jQuery for this?

```css
#vr {
  height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #808080;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #808080;
  -webkit-transition: 1000ms ease in;
  -moz-transition: 1000ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: 1000ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: 1000ms ease-in;
  transition: 1000ms ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -12px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  width: 1px;
  float:right;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#content {
  width: 180px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bigger() {
    document.getElementById("vr").style.height = "100px";
  }
</script>

<body onload="bigger()">
  <div id="content">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>

  <hr id="vr" />
</body>
```

Is the `height()` function useful in this context?

Comment: how about updating the height of second object when read more is clicked ? I mean listening to the click event. Also can you please provide a sample that actually has a read more button ?

Answer (score 1):

Make the function that is called by the "read more" button measure the element's offsetHeight, and then set the height of the second element. (The example uses `box-sizing: border-box` for simplicity, otherwise you have to take padding/border/margin sizes into account.)

```js
function addListener() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("div1");
    if (elem) elem.addEventListener("click", showMore, false)
    else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addListener, false);
}
addListener();

function showMore() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("div1");
    elem.style.maxHeight = "1000px";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.height = elem.offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
DIV {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
DIV {width: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;}
#div1 {max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden;}
#div2 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<DIV ID="div1">click this container to extend its height, so that the whole text becomes visible.</DIV>
<DIV ID="div2"></DIV>
```

Comment: offsetHeight includes padding and border; clientHeight includes padding only. (In jQuery, outerHeight(true) also includes the margin.)