# Shorten height of div when user types text in an input div above and makes it taller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs, and want them to resize based on each other's heights. As I enter text in the input in Div1, it can grow. If it grows taller than the original height of 40px, Div2 should shrink by the number of pixels Div has grown. For example, Div1 starts off as height:40px and Div2 with height: 100px. I enter long text and Div1 grows to 60px, Div2 should shrink by 20px and have height 80px.

Entering content in Div 2 should not affect content in Div1, so I have set Div2 to `overflow-y: auto`.

How do I do this? This is what I have, but the javascript is not working. 
`var height = $('#inputText').height();` keeps returning 17.600 (I don't really know what this number means, it's not px). `var height = document.getElementById('inputId').style.height;` returns the original 40px all the time. These numbers don't change even when the div grows. How can I get the new height when there are 2 lines of text in it?

Sorry for the lengthy question, hope this makes sense. Thank you.

html

```
<div class="div1"
    <input class="inputText" id="inputId" style="width: 230px; height: inherit">
</div>

<div class="editableContent" id="editorId" contentEditable="true" role="textbox"></div>
```

css

```
.relate {
   border-bottom: 1 px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
   height: 40px
}

 .relate input.inputText {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem; 
  }

  .editableContent {
     display: block;
     width: 300px;
     height: 100px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  }
```

js

```
var height = $('#inputText').height();
if (height > document.getElementById('inputId').style.height) {
   document.getElementById('editorId').style.height -= height; 
}
```

Comment: You need an event listener, which starts the calculation, when the user makes changes in the field. It could be one of the following events: keyup, keydown, change, blur.

Comment: Thanks @Joerg, I just added it within a keydown event. But, my question is why is `height()` still not working. It keeps returning a constant value, even when the div grows. I know the event works because when I print the newly entered text, it's correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482415/use-height-of-another-element-dynamically/31484529#31484529

Answer (score 0):

In your height definition, you are calling an id, which doesn't exist:

```
var height = $('.inputText').height();

or:

var height = $('#inputId').height();
```